# &__get() issues, again. Major frustration is afoot

Tags: php, reference, getter, magic-methods

Alrighty, I'm getting quite frustrated, namely because I thought I had this issue solved, or had accomplished this successfully before.

Quick preliminary:

- PHP 5.3.6.
- Error reporting cranked to 11. (*`-1` actually; future safe, all errors/notices*)

I have a class, it aggregates request parameters. For giggles here is a stripped down version:

```
class My_Request{
    private $_data = array();
    public function __construct(Array $params, Array $session){
        $this->_data['params']  = $params;
        $this->_data['session'] = $session;
    }
    public function &__get($key){
        // arrg!
    }
}
```

Anyways, the reason for `arrg!` is, **no matter what I try, I always get an error whenever the `$key` doesn't exist.** I've tried:

```
// doesn't work
$null = null;
if(isset($this->_data[$key])){ return $this->_data[$key]; }
return $null;

// doesn't work
return $this->_data[$key];
```

I've been told ternary operators cannot result in a reference, ergo, that of course doesn't work, but we know that from the `if` condition attempt anyways. What happens, for example:

```
// params will have foo => bar, and session hello => world
$myRequest = new My_Request(array('foo' => 'bar'), array('hello' => 'world'));

// throws an error - Undefined index: baz
echo $myRequest->params['baz'];
```

I'm losing my mind here; perhaps I hallucinated a scenario where I achieved this. Is it not possible to (*without throwing a notice*) successfully do this?

---

Clarification: *Things I've tried*

The aforementioned:

```
// no check, no anything, just try returning : fails
public function &__get($key){
    return $this->_data[$key];
}

// null variable to pass back by reference : fails
public function &__get($key){
    $null = null;
    if(isset($this->_data[$key])){
        return $this->_data[$key];
    }
    return $null;
}
```

Other attempts:

```
// can't work - can't return null by reference nor via ternary : fails
public function &__get($key){
    return isset($this->_data[$key])
        ? $this->_data[$key]
        : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo $myRequest->params['baz'];
```

The isset check in your `__get` function will look up `"params"` from `$this->_data` and return the array. The notice you get is from outside the class and about a key `"baz"` in the returned array - which in your example was never actually defined.

Comment: Thanks **mario**; Fair enough, I'm returning by reference to support multidimensional arrays, so.. the million dollar question is how can I verify the existence of a nested key? I'd have to iterate the nested arrays, but I don't have the necessary information available, as in all of the keys associated with each level of the multidimensional array.

Comment: Simple answer: you cannot. -- It would require extremely elaborate workarounds, wrapping the returned array into an ArrayObject (implicit reference for simplicity), and overriding the access methods there alike. (Needs to apply itself recursively for further arrays..)

Comment: Ah, dammit, another interface to implement, and I don't wanna turn down error reporting, I've come to like it. Is `__get()` by reference a feature or a bug? If it's a feature, I hope it was an afterthought.

Comment: Another elaboration: Given I was working directly with an array - say `public $params = array();` - What could I do in these circumstances? Is there any reasonable support for checking nested key existence at all?

Comment: It's an intended feature (though was buggy IIRC). But seeing the subarray access from the higher level `__get` or `offsetGet` access is simply infeasible to implement at the language level. I'm not aware of any other langauge which would allow that. (Also: yes, I failed at implementing something like this myself. Twice.)

Comment: You certainly recall correctly. This is my first failed attempt, however I'm starting to think my memory of success predates my usage of `error_reporting(-1)`. Damn again. Damn. Is it worth ditching the cranked error reporting to support this? I feel dirty just thinking about it.

Comment: What do you need it for? Maybe you can get away with a single level of workarounds for your $session and $params array. Just implement a `QuietArray extends ArrayObject` and be good.

Comment: I'm perusing the docs on `ArrayObject`, haven't used it before - any suggested reading for this specific implementation or similar?

Comment: Actually look into ArrayAccess to override it. Use `offsetGet` in place of `__get` and then simply neglect to send a notice for missing array keys.

Comment: Awesome. Doing it, and it appears to be working. Only problem is any logic I had performing tasks like `array_merge` are going to need to be changed. Any thoughts on that, or am I stuck for array function support?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just cast to `Array`, run array functions, and create a new object with the result. Thanks a ton **mario**; would +10 if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is stale, but I just stumbled on it via Google while looking for the answer (which I have since found).

```
class My_Request{
    private $_data = array();
    public function __construct(Array $params, Array $session){
        $this->_data['params']  = $params;
        $this->_data['session'] = $session;
    }
    public function &__get($key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->_data)) {
            return &$this->_data[$key]; // Note the reference operator
        } else {
            $value = null; // First assign null to a variable
            return $value; // Then return a reference to the variable
        }
    }
}
```

`$this->_data[$key]` is an operation that returns a value, so returning the value will result in an error because it's not a reference. To make it return a reference instead, you have to use the reference: `&$this->_data[$key]`.

Comment: Thanks @Dagan! I've since changed my approach, favoring instead a sort of parsed path traversal, for `$o->get('foo.bar.qux');` which translates roughly (*internally*) to `$this->data['foo']['bar']['qux'];`. I can return by reference without issue given the traversal approach.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this because I avoid `__get` and `__set`, but maybe this would work for you:

```
public function __get($key){
   if(!isset($this->_data[$key]))
       return false;

   return $this->_data[$key];    
}
```

Totally untested, but it looks like it could maybe do the job.

Comment: Thanks **stefgosselin**; No, returning `false` by reference is the same. Much in the way returning `$false = false` by reference is the same as my `$null = null` attempt.

Comment: Yeah. I see. I am reading up on [returning references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) to better understand what you were trying to do, but it's not too clear I'll admit.  There are a lot of good comments to get a better picture of how one handles returning references, but I have never used returned references so I still have to  let it soak it in a bit. Good luck friend ;)