# Altering a class variable that's an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, class-variables

I've done extensive searching, and found this:

[&__get() issues, again. Major frustration is afoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287982/get-issues-again-major-frustration-is-afoot)

However, none of the examples provided actually work.

I've got a object that has a variable which is a multi-dimensional array.  I need to alter the value of a key in that array.

Example:

```
foreach ($code->files as $index => $value)
{
    if (strcmp($code->files[$index]['id'], $fileid) == 0)
    {                               
        $code->files[$index]['title'] = "Test";
        $code->save();  
    }
}
```

The above code does generates the error:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CodeDocument::$files has no effect in /var/www/deletefile.php on line 57
```

I've tried all the examples in the previously referenced thread link, and none of them work.  They all generate the error above.

I am using a prebuilt class library (phpillow), but I tried altering the __get function to be &__get and it supresses the error above, but the variable I am trying to change still does not get a new value.

I am not sure if I am doing this right, but I am at a total loss.  Doing this without putting an array as the class variable would require a LOT of refactoring that I'd rather avoid doing if at all possible.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the code of `CodeDocument` ?

Comment: Can you show your `__set()` function ?

Comment: You don't show the most important part: what does `__get` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
foreach ($code->files as $index => $value)
{
    if (strcmp($value['id'], $fileid) == 0)
    {                               
       $value['title'] = "Test";
       $code->save();  
    }
}
```

Comment: It seemed to get rid of the message I was getting, but it still did not change the value.

Comment: I think the problem may be that `__get` can't really return a reference, because methods that return references have to be called with `&`. Instead of using `__get`, use a normal method and call it with reference syntax.